# Poco log lines from different thread overwrite each other

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, poco-libraries

I have two different threads both logging to separate `Poco::WindowsColorConsoleChannel` channels.

However sometimes the messages appear interleaved, e.g. if one thread logs `aaaaaaa` and the other logs `bbbbbbbb` then the screen may look like `abbbbbaaaaaabbb`.

The threads are using completely different `Logger` objects and different channel objects.

The same thing happens if using the default channel. The problem is particularly pronounced with the color console channel as it makes the colours look like the wrong lines are being coloured.

Is there a way to make each log line 'atomic'?

*Note:* I haven't yet checked to see if the same problem occurs when logging to a `SimpleFileChannel`, but if so then I would need a solution for that too :)

Comment: Of course it'd be possible to wrap every call to a logger in a critical section but I'm hoping for something nicer, e.g. something built into the logging framework to be able to handle this.

Comment: How exactly are you creating these different logger objects?

Comment: @Alex The thread is using `Poco::Logger::get("bla")` and the main app is using `logger()` member function of `Poco::Application`, in each case I attached the WindowsColorConsoleChannel by using `setChannel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a "solution". It has some flaws:  it's probably reinventing the wheel, it might not be idiomatic for Poco (I'm fairly new to Poco), and I'm worried that there might be a deadlock if exceptions are thrown during thread or application shutdown.

But it seems to work for now.

In header file:

```
    struct RC_Semaphore: Poco::Semaphore, Poco::RefCountedObject
    {
        using Poco::Semaphore::Semaphore;
    };

    struct SemaphoreLock
    {
        SemaphoreLock(Poco::Semaphore &sem): sem(sem) { sem.wait(); }
        ~SemaphoreLock() { sem.set(); }

        Poco::Semaphore &sem;
    };

    struct SynchronizingChannel: Poco::Channel, noncopyable
    {
        SynchronizingChannel(Poco::AutoPtr<RC_Semaphore> sem, Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Channel> dest)
            : sem(sem), dest(dest) {}

        virtual void log(const Poco::Message& msg)
        {
            SemaphoreLock lock(*sem);
            dest->log(msg);
        }

    private:
        Poco::AutoPtr<RC_Semaphore> sem;
        Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Channel> dest;
    } ;
```

Usage:

```
// Synchronization for log channels outputting to console
    auto semConsole = make_AutoPtr<RC_Semaphore>(1);

// Logging channel - main
    auto chanMainRaw = make_AutoPtr<Poco::WindowsColorConsoleChannel>();
    chanMainRaw->setProperty("debugColor", "green");
    auto chanMain = make_AutoPtr<SynchronizingChannel>(semConsole, chanMainRaw);

// Channel that will be used by thread
    auto chanThreadRaw = make_AutoPtr<Poco::WindowsColorConsoleChannel>();
    chanThreadRaw->setProperty("debugColor", "magenta");
    auto chanThread = make_AutoPtr<SynchronizingChannel>(semConsole, chanThreadRaw);

// (other code to set up filters can go here)

    logger().setChannel(chanMain);
    OtherThread::logger().setChannel(chanThread);
```

NB. `make_AutoPtr` is the same as `std::make_unique` but with `Poco::AutoPtr` instead, I use it to avoid having to duplicate the type name.

Answer (score 2):

ConsoleChannel logging operation is protected with a [static FastMutex](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/ConsoleChannel.cpp#L45-L50). However, to provide proper Unicode text logging, on Windows the ConsoleChannel [defaults to WindowsConsoleChannel](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/LoggingFactory.cpp#L92), which converts UTF-8 to UTF-16.

So, the Application::logger() will likely have the default WindowsConsoleChannel, while the thread has ConsoleChannel (or Color* versions thereof); in any case you must have a mix of different channels to see the effect you are describing - although the destination is the same, you are logging through different channels, which are protected by different mutexes. I think it would make sense for Poco to protect all console channels with a single static mutex to avoid problems like this.

Given all this, the code example you posted above should work fine even without the custom synchronization scheme.

Note also that, whenever you are logging to the same console channel type, your threads will be waiting for each other during every log operation. To avoid the bottleneck, you may consider using [AsyncChannel](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/AsyncChannel.h).

(Simple)FileChannel is protected by a [non-static FastMutex](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/FileChannel.h#L259), so it will not suffer from the same problem as long as each thread is logging into its own file or they all log to the same file through the same channel instance. I never tried the latter but intuitively it does not sound like the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes, I am logging through two different WindowsConsoleChannels because I wanted the thread to use a different colour scheme.  I guess another solution to the same problem would be to log through the same channel, but add custom log levels for the thread so I can give them their own colour.   I'll try to make a MCVE instead of just describing the code.

Comment: Logging through different channels of the same type is thread safe. The problem occurs when logging from two threads through console channels of different types.

Comment: I'm definitely using two WindowsColorConsoleChannel because I create them using `new Poco::WindowsColorConsoleChannel`. I will make up a MCVE as I must be doing something wrong elsewhere if that is supposed to work properly.